# Get values from a lists of hashmaps and put into one list?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have list where each element is a dictionary.

```
myList = [
{mykey1:myValue1, myKey2:myValue2},
{myKey1:myValue1b, myKey2:myValue2b}
]
```

I want a CSV file with just values for each entry. To get this, I need a list where each element is a string of comma separate values. So it would be of the form:

```
myValuesOnlyList=[ "myValue1, myValue2",
"myValue1b, myValue2b"]
```

To do this, I do something like:

```
for mydict in myList:
    row = ','.join(str(e) for e in mydict.values());
    myValuesOnlyList.append(row);
```

IS there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable.

Comment: And you can't have duplicate keys in a dict...as you do right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`csv.DictWriter` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), it'll write the values directly for you:

```
fields = ('mykey1', 'mykey2', ...)
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
    writer.writerow({f: f for f in fields})  # write a header row
    for entry in myList:
        write.writerow(entry)
```

Comment: Good but how do I get my headers into the CSV?  I want first row to be headers?

Comment: @dublintech: updated; just write an extra `dict` generated from the `fields` tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of your `for` loop and use a list comprehension:

```
[",".join(str(v) for v in d.itervalues()) for d in myList]
```

Note that as a dictionary is unordered, you can't predict the order in which the different values will be returned (which could be a serious problem).

Comment: If you need the order preserved, use collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

#### Generic Example:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```